# Iframe Redirection

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm currently have some issue with an iframe.

I have my iframe with a searchbox and i want to make this searchbox redirection when i click on go... But nothing works and i can't understand what i have to do...

http://img51.imageshack.us/i/issuec.png/

EDIT : 24/02/2011
So to be clear, my google chrome extension call as a content script : overlay.js Then this one will put at the end of the current page my "overlay.html" page.

So the problem come from that my .html is represented as a iframe and i don't see how i can redirect from this iframe

overlay.html

```
<form id="searchForm" action="#" onsubmit="searchBoxRedirection(this)" method="post">
<img id="logo" src="images/extension.png" alt="Logo"></img>
<input type="search" value="" name="searching">
<input type="submit" value="Go !" /> 
</form>
```

overlay.js

```
var overlay= {
    init: function() {
        this.injectoverlay();
        //alert('Initialisation reussie');
    },

    injectoverlay: function() {
        var body = $('body'),
            overlayURL = chrome.extension.getURL("overlay.html"),
            iframe = $('<iframe id="YouroverlayFrame" src="'+overlayURL+'">');

            body.append(iframe);
            iframe.show();

        //alert('Injection reussie');
    }
}
```

Tool.js

```
function searchBoxRedirection(form)
{
    //alert(form.searching.value);
    //tabs.create({url:"www.yahoo.fr"});
    //parent.chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://blackweb20.com/"});
    //parent.location.href='www.yahoo.fr';
    //chrome.tabs.update({url:"http://www.siteduzero.com",selected:true});

    //chrome.windows.create({url:"http://www.siteduzero.com"});
}
```

manifest.json

```
{   

    "background_page" : "background.html",
    "browser_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "images/Extension.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": 
    [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "css": ["css/overlay.css"],
      "js": ["js/overlay.js"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    } ], 
    "permissions" : ["tabs", "unlimitedStorage", "http://*/*"], 
    "name" : "MyOverlay",
    "version" : "1.1",
    "description" : "Sindar Overlay"
}
```

**Update**

I've find a part of the answer by using :

```
function searchBoxRedirection(form)
{
    window.top.location.href = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + form.searching.value;
}
```

But for the creation of new tab, or a new window it didn't work...

Comment: What are you doing using what programming language? Are you working on a Chrome extension? I don't understand

Comment: you need to give way more info dude

Comment: Basicely it's an google Chrome Extension that inject an iframe on every html page. An i want to make search with this iframe by redirection with JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide some code (the more the better)

Comment: And in which file do you include tool.js, in overlay.html? So everything inside `searchBoxRedirection(form)` completely isn't working (it doesn't create new tabs?)

Comment: Yeah in the overlay.hmtl, nothing work.

Comment: Please provide your manifest as well.

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work, `chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://blackweb20.com/"});` and similar should be working

Comment: @Sindar - Please simply edit your question to provide additional information. Answers are reserved for solutions only. Additionally, can you flag the question that you posted as an unregistered user so it can be closed / removed and your accounts merged?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a new chrome tab/window from a Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115606/create-a-new-chrome-tab-window-from-a-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

This question is the exact duplicate (word by word) of:
[Create a new chrome tab/window from a Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115606/create-a-new-chrome-tab-window-from-a-iframe)

To summarize, you have two choices:

- Use [Messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to redirect the page.
- Call "parent" within the iframe to do a redirect.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment.