# Create a new chrome tab/window from a Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently have some issue with an iframe...

I have my iframe with a searchbox and i want to make this searchbox redirection when i click on go by creating a new tab/window

http://img51.imageshack.us/i/issuec.png/

So to be clear, my google chrome extension call as a content script : overlay.js Then this one will put at the end of the current page my "overlay.html" page.

So the problem come from that my .html is represented as a iframe and i don't see how i can redirect from this iframe.

overlay.html

```
<form id="searchForm" action="#" onsubmit="searchBoxRedirection(this)" method="post">
<img id="logo" src="images/extension.png" alt="Logo"></img>
<input type="search" value="" name="searching">
<input type="submit" value="Go !" /> 
</form>
```

overlay.js

```
var overlay= {
    init: function() {
        this.injectoverlay();
        //alert('Initialisation reussie');
    },

    injectoverlay: function() {
        var body = $('body'),
            overlayURL = chrome.extension.getURL("overlay.html"),
            iframe = $('<iframe id="YouroverlayFrame" src="'+overlayURL+'">');

            body.append(iframe);
            iframe.show();

        //alert('Injection reussie');
    }
}
```

Tool.js

```
function searchBoxRedirection(form)
{
    tabs.create({url:"www.yahoo.fr"});
}
```

manifest.json

```
{   

    "background_page" : "background.html",
    "browser_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "images/Extension.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": 
    [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "css": ["css/overlay.css"],
      "js": ["js/overlay.js"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    } ], 
    "permissions" : ["tabs", "unlimitedStorage", "http://*/*"], 
    "name" : "MyOverlay",
    "version" : "1.1",
    "description" : "Sindar Overlay"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your using [Content-Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) you cannot call any Chrome API except a few chrome.extensions.*

Here are some examples of what content scripts can do:

## Documentation Quote

> Find unlinked URLs in web pages and
>   convert them into hyperlinks'
>
> - Increase the font size to make text more legible
> - Find and process microformat data in the DOM
>
> However, content scripts have some
>   limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content
>     scripts
> - Make cross-site XMLHttpRequests

Now to do what you want, you need to goto a link, you have two choices:

1. Use [Messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to redirect the page.
2. Call "parent" within the iframe to do a redirect.

## Messaging approach

Messaging is simple, all you do is send a request to the extension which will `chrome.tabs.create` the new page.

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({visit: "http://yahoo.fr"});
```

**background.html**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.visit) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: request.visit});
  }
  sendRepsonse({}); // Snub
});
```

## Parent approach

**Content Script injects:**

```
<iframe src='iframe.html'></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeURL(url) {
 document.location=url;
   }        
</script>
```

**IFrame contains:**

```
 <a href="javascript:parent.changeURL('http://yahoo.fr');">Change to Yahoo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same thing, but unfortunately not aware where to put the below code

Parent approach

```
Content Script injects:

<iframe src='iframe.html'></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeURL(url) {
 document.location=url;
   }        
</script>
IFrame contains:

 <a href="javascript:parent.changeURL('http://yahoo.fr');">Change to Yahoo</a>
```